# How do I draw the following Keras model?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, visualization

I am new to deep learning models, and I am trying to figure out the best way to draw a visual representation of the following model. I found a [few tools](https://github.com/ashishpatel26/Tools-to-Design-or-Visualize-Architecture-of-Neural-Network) that allow you to draw a model, but I am confused about what the 'best' way to draw this particular model would be.

[image]

Any suggestions or recommendations would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should Go along with **Tensorboard**, it looks more *professional* than the rest and it is easier to understand the model.

May I ask your exact purpose for the visualization? You could check others material with the similar purpose and go along with the general choice! Many would go for **draw_convnet** or **PlotNeuralNet** if the final use-case was to publish a *blog.* It also depends on which libraries and softwares you are using!

Comment: thanks for the response! The visualization is for a presentation. I have never drawn a model like this before, and i'm confused about the layers. I can give TensorBoard a try, can you recommend a tutorial for me to follow?

Comment: It's okay to be confused, everyone is at the beginning! Here is the link: https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/graphs It was in the link you provided yourself!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tf.keras.utils.plot_model`. For instance this example given in the tensorflow doc:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(100,), dtype='int32', name='input')
x = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
    output_dim=512, input_dim=10000, input_length=100)(input)
x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='output')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[output])
dot_img_file = 'model_1.png'
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, to_file=dot_img_file, show_shapes=True)
```

you get the following:

[image]

For this function to work you need to install the dependencies:

- pydot (pip3 install pydot)
- an graphviz (install will depend on your OS) have a look at this [link](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/)